# Sum over all non-evil numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

I'm working on the following contest math problem:

> Define an *evil* number to be any positive integer that contains the
>   digit $9$. Show that
>
> $$ \sum_{x} \frac{1}{x} < 80 $$
>
> where the sum is over all non-evil positive integers $x$.

I'm very confused on where to begin. Initially, I tried to consider this sum as part of the sum of $1/x$ over all positive integers, namely by noting that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{x} \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{y} \frac{1}{y}
$$

where the first summation on the right side is the same as in the problem statement and the second is the sum over all evil numbers. However, I can't seem to find a way to use this since the sum of the left diverges.

Could anyone lend a helping hand?

Comment: This is clearly false in base 9.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum 1/n=\infty$

Comment: Hint: There are $8$ non-evil numbers with one digit. $8\times 9$ non-evil numbers with two digits, $8 \times 9^2$ non-evil number with three digits, ...

Comment: I imagine this has been on MSE before. For a discussion please see [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series)

Comment: @AndréNicolas http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387/sum-of-reciprocals-of-numbers-with-certain-terms-omitted and the linked questions there.

Comment: Thanks, I was sure I had seen it on MSE, but have limited searching skills, and often find it easier to prove than to find.  Have also seen it a bunch of other places, it is a golden oldie.

Answer (score 3):

There are $8\cdot9^{k-1}$ $k$ digit numbers without a $9$. Even if we take $8\cdot9^{k-1}$ times the reciprocal of the smallest $k$ digit number, we get the overestimate
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=10^{k-1}}^{10^{k-1}+8\cdot9^{k-1}-1}\frac1j
&\le8\left(\frac9{10}\right)^{k-1}
\end{align}
$$
Add these up for $k\ge1$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty8\left(\frac9{10}\right)^{k-1}
&=8\frac1{1-\frac9{10}}\\
&=80
\end{align}
$$