# Tricky harmonic sum without some terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to prove that the harmonic sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$$

converges when we remove all the terms $\frac1n$ where the decimal expansion of $n$ contains the digit $9$.

I have a hint but don't know how to use it; how many terms of at most $k$ digits are there?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series

Comment: There are many question on math.SE covering this sort of sum. Look at answers of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/387/59379) and the "Linked" questions there.