# Sum of reciprocals of integers with one digit missing

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I'm reading Hardy's wonderful book on theory of numbers. At some point he is proving that "almost all" integer numbers contain digit 9 (or any other sequence of digits, like "9345"). It's fairly obvious: number of integers up to $n$ digits is $a_n=10^n-1$. Number of integers up to $n$ digits with digit 9 missing is $b_n=9^n-1$. And because $\lim_{n\to\infty}{b_n}/{a_n}=0$ it means that $b_n \ll a_n$ for big enough $n$. In other words, the number of integers without digit 9 is "neglectable" (comparatively small).

So far so good, but in the footnote Hardy mentiones an interesting consequence without proof. Let $n$ be any number that is missing decimal digit 9. The following "quasiharmonic" sum is convergent:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1n=\frac11+\frac12+\dots+\frac17+\frac18+\frac1{10}+\frac1{11}+\dots\frac1{18}+\frac1{20}+\frac1{21}+\dots$$

It also means that the sum of reciprocals of all numbers containing digit 9 must be divergent:

$$\frac19+\frac1{19}+\frac1{29}\dots+\frac1{89}+\frac1{90}+\frac1{91}+\frac1{92}+\dots$$

Is there a simple proof for this?

Comment: Can't you compare it with $\sum\frac{9}{10}^n$ by grouping the terms, the ones up to $\frac{1}{10}$ at most $9$, up to $\frac{1}{100}$ at most $\frac{9}{10}$ of this etc etc

Comment: You are looking for : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387/sum-of-reciprocals-of-numbers-with-certain-terms-omitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [Kempner series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series). You can find the proof in Hardy's book, Apostol, or on Wikipedia.

The basic idea is to order the denominators by how many digits they contain. There are $8\cdot 9^{n-1}$ numbers with $n$ digits having no 9 in them, and each of them is larger than $10^{n-1}$. Thus the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{8\cdot 9^{n-1}}{10^{n-1}}$$
is an upper-bound to $\sum_{\text{$n$ has no $9$'s}}\frac 1n$, which you can evaluate as a geometric series to get that it equals $\boxed{80}$.